# Spring data jpa multiple table join with subquery

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

This is SQL Query I have tried to join all the tables using Spring Data JPA. Some please help me out.

```
SELECT op.id AS "Profile ID",
       op.organization_name AS "Organization name",
       pav.annotation AS "legacy-sams-acc-id",
       ip.subnet AS "CIDR IP range"
FROM profile.profile p
        JOIN profile.organization_profile op ON op.id = p.id
        JOIN profile.profile_annotation_type pat ON pat.publisher_id = p.supplier_publisher_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (SELECT pa.id AS id,
                    pa.profile_id AS profile_id,
                    ftpa.annotation AS annotation, 
                    ftpa.free_text_profile_annotation_type_id AS free_text_profile_annotation_type_id
             FROM profile.profile_annotation pa
                      JOIN profile.free_text_profile_annotation ftpa ON ftpa.id = pa.id
            ) AS pav ON pav.free_text_profile_annotation_type_id = pat.id AND pav.profile_id = p.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN profile.ip_range_identifier ip ON ip.organization_profile_id = op.id
WHERE pat.description = 'legacy-sams-acc-id'
      AND p.supplier_publisher_id = 66
ORDER BY op.id ASC
```

Following will be the corresponding Java class. I'm struck with converting SQL to Java.

```
    public Specification<OrganizationProfile> organizationProfileReportCriteria(Long publisherId) {
        
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            
            Subquery<Profile> profileSubquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Profile.class);
            Root<Profile> profileRoot = profileSubquery.from(Profile.class);
            Join<Profile, OrganizationProfile> profileOrganizationProfileJoin = profileRoot.join("supplierPublisher");
    
            profileSubquery.select(profileRoot)
                    .where(criteriaBuilder.equal(profileOrganizationProfileJoin, root),
                            criteriaBuilder.equal(profileRoot.get("supplierPublisher").get("id"), publisherId));
            
           
            Subquery<ProfileAnnotationType> profileAnnotationTypeSubquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(ProfileAnnotationType.class);
            Root<ProfileAnnotationType> profileAnnotationTypeRoot = profileAnnotationTypeSubquery.from(ProfileAnnotationType.class);
            
            Join<ProfileAnnotationType, OrganizationProfile> organizationProfileAnnotationTypeJoin
                    = profileAnnotationTypeRoot.join("publisher");
            
            profileAnnotationTypeSubquery.select(profileAnnotationTypeRoot)
                    .where(criteriaBuilder.equal(organizationProfileAnnotationTypeJoin, root),
                            criteriaBuilder.equal(profileAnnotationTypeRoot.get("publisher").get("id"), publisherId));
            
            
            Subquery<ProfileAnnotation> profileAnnotationSubquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(ProfileAnnotation.class);
            Root<ProfileAnnotation> profileAnnotationRoot = profileAnnotationTypeSubquery.from(ProfileAnnotation.class);
            
            Join<ProfileAnnotation, OrganizationProfile> profileAnnotationOrganizationJoin
                    = profileAnnotationRoot.join("profile");
            
            profileAnnotationSubquery.select(profileAnnotationRoot)
                    .where(criteriaBuilder.equal(profileAnnotationOrganizationJoin, root),
                            criteriaBuilder.equal(profileAnnotationRoot.get("profile").get("supplierPublisher").get("id"), publisherId));
             
            return criteriaBuilder.or(criteriaBuilder.exists(profileSubquery));
        };
    }
```

Basically, I'm not sure how to join multiple tables using JPA. Someone, please explain to me how to convert multiple join and Subquery for converting SQL to Java. Basically confusion about profile and Organization profile table.

Comment: JPQL doesn't support subqueries in the `FROM` clause. It would also be helpful to have the entity classes to answer your question.